# Is there a way to specify what the legend shows in Altair?

Tags: altair

I have the following graph in Altair:
[image]

The code used to generate it is as follows:

```
data = pd.read_csv(data_csv)
display(data)
display(set(data['algo_score_raw']))
# First generate base graph
base = alt.Chart(data).mark_circle(opacity=1, stroke='#4c78a8').encode(
    x=alt.X('Paragraph:N', axis=None),
    y=alt.Y('Section:N', sort=list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(data['Section']))),
    size=alt.Size('algo_score_raw:Q', title="Number of Matches"),
).properties(
    width=900,
    height=500
)

# Next generate the overlying graph with the lines

lines = alt.Chart(data).mark_rule(stroke='#4c78a8').encode(
    x=alt.X('Paragraph:N', axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=0)),
    y=alt.Y('Section:N', sort=list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(data['Section'])))
).properties(
    width=900,
    height=500
)
if max(data['algo_score_raw']) == 0:
    return lines # no circles if no matches
else:
    return base + lines
```

However, I don't want the decimal values in my legend; I only want 1.0, 2.0, and 3.0, because those are the only values that are actually present in my data. However, Altair seems to default to what you see above.

Answer (score 0):

The legend is generated based on how you specify your encoding. It sounds like your data are better represented as ordered categories than as a continuous quantitative scale. You can specify this by changing the encoding type to `ordinal`:

```python
    size=alt.Size('algo_score_raw:O')
```

You can read more about encoding types at https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/encoding.html

Comment: Thank you for this! This mostly works, but causes a separate issue where now, the "0" dots, which I wanted to be invisible, show up as tiny dots for the "0" marker on the legend.

Comment: @MurtazaAli you've likely figured this out by now, but you can use a Filter Transform to filter out the 0 dots before plotting. Or, just filter the zeroes out of your data in pandas before passing to Altair. Filter Transform docs: https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/filter.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alt.Legend(tickCount=2))` (`labelExpr` could also be helpful, [see the docs for more](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/legend.html#legend-properties)):

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data


source = data.cars()
source['Acceleration'] = source['Acceleration'] / 10

chart = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    size='Acceleration',
)
chart
```

[image]

```py
chart.encode(size=alt.Size('Acceleration', legend=alt.Legend(tickCount=2)))
```

[image]